# Javascript Add text/html to div Alternative ways

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I know that in order to append some text/html to a div I in javascript (no jquery) I would do this:

```
var div = document.getElementById('mydiv');
    div.innerHTML = 'Something to append';
```

I know it's only 2 lines of code but is there a shorter way to do this without using jquery?

ES6 comes with lots of goodies to make things happen writing less code.

I was wondering if this is the only way to do this?

Comment: why can't you do `document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML = 'changed';`

Comment: @Kinduser sorry I just checked two `=` signs in your answer and thought you're kind of assigning the div and its value again to a variable which was not needed. your code is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually there's no any feature in ES6 to write it even quicker, but you can always just refer to the `innerHTML` attribute directly.

```
document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML = 'Something to append';
```

Comment: @MehulMohan *"but is there a shorter way to do this?"* Shorter `!=` more readable.

Comment: @MehulMohan why is it ugly to read? This type of chaining syntax is the backbone of most javascript.

Comment: I meant the version before you edited. This one is obviously fine @Soviut

Comment: haha i was in a hurry. i didn't see that your code had a little typo, just saw it as another way of doing the same thing

Comment: @MehulMohan Chill :-)